# How get control from control group, which is part of another control group

Tags: typescript, angular

Good day. I need to check is control valid or no for changing view on page. I need to check control, called `pin` in `createdPins`, which is part of `pinFrom`. I do it this way:

```
showConformationOfPIN() {   
    console.log("here"); 
    if (this.pinForm.controls['createdPins']['pin'].valid)
    {
        this.confirmPIN = true;
        console.log("true");
    }
}
```

And I get the error, that `this.pinForm.controls.createdPins.pin` is undefined.
This is constructor where I initialize pinForm:

```
private pinForm: ControlGroup;

constructor(private passPin: PassPinService, 
            controls: FormBuilder,
            private checkInp: CheckInputsService,
            previousPage?: RouteParams) { 
    ..............

    this.pinForm = controls.group({
        pinLog: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)])],
        createdPins: controls.group({
            pin: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)])],
            pinConfirmation: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(4)])] },
            {validator: this.checkInp.areInputsEqual}  ) 
    });      
}
```

And this is part of template, where I binded pinForm:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="pinForm" class="centerMain">
        <div ngControlGroup="createdPins">
            <div *ngIf="!confirmPIN && prevPage == 'reg'" class="center-block">  <!-- this div should hides -->
                <div>
                    <label  class="center-block">Введите PIN</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input (keyup)="showConformationOfPIN()" ngControl="pin" [(ngModel)]="final" maxlength="4" placeholder="1234" 
                            class="center-block inputLine">
                </div>          
                <!--<div>
                    <button (click)="showConformationOfPIN()" class="center-block buttonBig">Установить PIN</button> 
                </div>-->
            </div>
            <!-- Confirmation of PIN -->
            <div *ngIf="confirmPIN && prevPage == 'reg'" class="center-block"> <!--this should appears -->
                <div>
                    <label  class="center-block">Подтвердите пин</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input ngControl="pinConfirmation" maxlength="4" placeholder="1234" class="center-block inputLine">
                </div>          
                <div>
                    <button (click)="sendPIN()" class="center-block buttonBig">Подтвердить</button> 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Günter's method should work, however you can also get it like this

```
this.pinForm.find('createdPins').find('pin')
```

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but I think it should be

```
this.pinForm.controls['createdPins'].controls['pin']
```

If you do for example `console.log(this.pinForm.control['createdPins'])` you can investigate in the browser console and verify if the `controls` property lists a `pin` control.

Comment: there is no property "controls" in controls['createdPins'], unfortunately. I tried it.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker of your example. It would make it easier to debug. I don't know it by heart. You might need to add `ngControlGroup="someName"` to the elements between `<div ngControlGroup="createdPins">` and the actual input element (as far as I remember - not sure though).